# Magento2.2: How to change the default functionality of search in visibility

Tags: magento2, search, visibility

I want to change the default functionality of search in visibility. When product Visibility is set to Search or Not Visible Individually it should not appear in the search dropdown, search results, or category pages.

Does anyone know the path to change it?

Comment: Before asking a new question, you should accept the answer to your previous questions.

Comment: @KeyurShah I already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **For Product Listing Page Copy This File in Your Theme**

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml
```

> **For Search Result Copy This File in Your Theme**

```
 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/result.phtml
```

**In This File You Can Apply Filter On Collection.**

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in backend:

1. click edit product and change Visibility attribute.

   or
2. select few products and select change attributes => change visibility.

[image]

Comment: I want search functionality to behave like not visible individually

Comment: You have option Not Visible Individually

Comment: yes, but the client wants the search to work like not visible individually

Comment: Do you want to hide search bar or products? If You check in product "Not visible Individually" this will hide this product.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Extension `setVisibility` method of below class:

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php
```